# How to get a sequence of words form uitextview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I am able to get the word on tapping uitextview but I want a sequence of words by tapping one of it. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJk9A.png) 
Over here in the image if I click on Australia I can get the name but for New Zealand I am only getting new or zealand. Is there any way I can get New Zealand as a whole word. My code is.

```
    countryTxtView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didReceiveGestureOnText(recognizer:))))

    @objc func didReceiveGestureOnText(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
        guard let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView else {return} 
        let point = recognizer.location(in: textView) 
        guard let detectedWord = getWordAtPosition(point, textView: textView) else {return} print("selected word : (detectedWord)")
    }

    func getWordAtPosition(_ point: CGPoint, textView: UITextView) -> String?{ 
        if let textPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: point){ 
            if let range = textView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(textPosition, with: .sentence, inDirection: UITextDirection(rawValue: 1)){ 
                return textView.text(in: range) 
            } 
        } 
        return nil 
     }
```

Comment: Please lineate and format your code. This is just plain illegible. If you care _about_ your question, care _for_ it.

Comment: I can't please a little help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Hey, I don't know where the line breaks go. Copy your code from Xcode and paste it into the question. Then it will be properly lineated. Then if necessary you can select it and mark it as code in the editor. Then it will be properly formatted. This is not hard.

Comment: Ok let me do that

Comment: yes done that now any help guys

Comment: Okay! So, you are tokenizing into words, but some countries have multiple words in their name. You will need to use smarter tokenization. Use an NLTagger with `.placeName` tag. Or if this format is guaranteed, you could just split on the comma-space separators.

Comment: Yes this formate is guaranteed. How can I split on the comma space separator?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-componentsseparatedby

Comment: Yeah that method is known to me but how can I know that which index of string I have tapped? Also it is a dynamic text it can be New Zealand it can north korea also

Comment: Tried a lot but nope not working in any way. Can you give me a solution @matt